# Java return ArrayList<MyObject> in medhot which returns an ArrayList of an Interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have two classes which have to getMethodes which returns an **ArrayList** of two Objects which implements a interface

```
public class MyClass1 implements IMyClasses<MyObject1>{

   public ArrayList<MyObject1> getMyObject() { ... }
}
public class MyClass2 implements IMyClasses<MyObject1>{

   public ArrayList<MyObject1> getMyObject() { ... }
}
```

**MyObject1** and **MyObject2** implements **IMyObject**

In my **ManagerClass** I would like to implement a function which can return any **IMyObject** implementation

```
ArrayList<IMyObject) get() {
   if (...) {
         return new MyClass1().getMyObject();
   } else {
         return new MyClass2().getMyObject();
   }
}
```

Before I have introduced the **Generic** typ on **MyClass1** and **MyClass2** it worked fine, but with the Generic which I need to get the proper object if needed, I'm not able to return the object which has as return type the Interface?

Some help?

**Edit** this is a full working example, the trick is to do `<? extend IMyObject>` thx to @Alexander.Furer

```
public class ManagerClassTest  {

    public interface IManagerClass {
        public ArrayList<? extends IMyObject> getMyObject(boolean myObject1);
    }

    public interface IMyClass<I>{
        public ArrayList<I> getMyObject();
    }

    public interface IMyObject {}

    public class MyObject1 implements IMyObject {}

    public class MyClass1 implements IMyClass<MyObject1> {

        @Override
        public ArrayList<MyObject1> getMyObject() {
            return new ArrayList<MyObject1>();
        }

    }

    public class MyObject2 implements IMyObject {}

    public class MyClass2 implements IMyClass<MyObject2> {

        @Override
        public ArrayList<MyObject2> getMyObject() {
            return new ArrayList<MyObject2>();
        }
    }


    public class ManagerClass implements IManagerClass {
        private ArrayList<MyObject1> getMyObject1() {
            return new MyClass1().getMyObject();
        }

        private ArrayList<MyObject2> getMyObject2() {
            return new MyClass2().getMyObject();
        }

        @Override
        public ArrayList<? extends IMyObject> getMyObject(boolean myObject1) {
            if (myObject1) {
                return new MyClass1().getMyObject();
            } else {
                return new MyClass2().getMyObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And you don't want to use `instanceof`?

Comment: You can also evaluate if its better to implement making use of the [Visitor Design Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm)

Comment: no in this case doing an instanceof is not that what I need

Comment: Not sure how I can reach my desired behavior with the visitor pattern, can you help starting from my second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList<MyObject1>` is not of type `ArrayList<IMyObject>` ,BTW, you have a typo :`ArrayList<IMyObject)`

Declare  the `get` method  of ManagerClass as :

```
ArrayList<? extends IMyObject> get() {
}
```

Comment: Thx man, your solution does work, i shared a full working example in my original post!!! THX

Comment: at the end how can I convert the return type ArrayList<?exends IMyObject> to my known Object in this case for example ArrayList<MyObject1>?

Comment: You can iterate over the list and cast each item according to `instance of`, but you can't convert list to known type because it's unknown: you are returning MyObject1 and MyObject2 items in the list. You should also check the visitor pattern as suggested earlier

Comment: Not sure how I can reach my desired behavior with the visitor pattern, can you help starting from my second example?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?